# How do i combine two numerical variables to create a new variable with the lowest value first based on the original variables in R?

Tags: r

I have a lot of data but i'll try to simplify it, this is also done in R. Let's say i have two variables X and Y:

```
X    Y   
100  101   
200  199   
300  301
```

I now want to combine these two variables but using the lowest value of the two variables before the separator "_". It should look like this:

```
X    Y     Z 
100  101   100_101
200  199   199_200
300  301   300_301
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
library(dplyr)
dt <- dt %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(z = paste(min(x,y),max(x,y),sep="_"))
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `pmin/pmap` (which is vectorized and is very efficient) to sort elementwise and then `paste` to create the new variable 'Z' in `base R`

```
df1$Z <- with(df1, paste(pmin(X, Y), pmax(X, Y), sep="_"))
```

---

Another efficient option is `dapply` from `collapse` to loop over the rows (`MARGIN = 1`), then `sort` by row and `paste` the elements

```
library(collapse)
df1$Z <-  dapply(df1, function(x) paste(sort(x), collapse="_"), MARGIN = 1)
```

---

Or using `apply` from `base R`

```
df1$Z <- apply(df1, 1, function(x) paste(sort(x), collapse="_"))
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(X = c(100L, 200L, 300L),
   Y = c(101L, 199L, 301L
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```